# Executing SUSE Linux commands from Oracle Forms 10g WebUtil

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

From an Oracle Forms 10g that I have, I am trying to run the following command:

`command:='fdisk -l | grep Disk ';`

While this does not throw any compile time errors, there appears to be no output. However, when I edit the same command as follows, there is no problem in generating the resultant output.

`command:='fdisk' ;`

I have the feeling that I may be making a mistake in forming the proper command string for execution.

Any assistance shall be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain the number of hard disk drives and the capacity of each, I was looking to make the command work:

```
command:='fdisk -l | grep Disk ';
```

Since, I could not, I figured that I needed to get the next alternative going and code a few extra lines to get the information that I wanted in Oracle Forms 10g. May be this would come in handy for those who may come across a similar problem. Following is the code section that has been tested and found to return the desired results.

```
    command:='fdisk -l ';
    process := WEBUTIL_HOST.Blocking(command);
    stnd := WEBUTIL_HOST.Get_Standard_Output(process);


    totalVal :=0;

        If stnd.count >= 1 Then        
        For i in stnd.first .. stnd.last Loop
            if(instr(UPPER(stnd(i)),UPPER('Disk /dev/sd'))>0) Then
            firstPos := instr(stnd(i),'Disk /dev/',1)+length('Disk /dev/sda:')+1;
            nextPos := instr(stnd(i),'GB',1);
            diffPos := nextPos - firstPos;

            extractPos := trim(substr(stnd(i),firstPos,diffPos));
            totalVal := totalVal+to_number(extractPos,'999999.9999999');


            end if; 

    End loop ;
```

I am sure the above could just as easily, if not more elegantly, have been done using pattern matching conditions.